# application.xml: error 102: Invalid namespace http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/23.0

Tags: xml, apache-flex, ipa, flashdevelop

When I package the ipa file use the PackageApp.bat in the FlashDevelop:

[image]

> C:\Users\Li\Desktop\ViShowMM application.xml: error 102: Invalid namespace http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/23.0
>
> APK setup creation FAILD.
>
> Troubleshooting:
>   - verify AIR SDK target version in application.xml

My `application.xml` is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/23.0">
  <id>com.ovmeet.ViShow.ViShow</id>
  <versionNumber>1.1<ersionNumber>
  <supportedProfiles>mobileDevice</supportedProfiles>
  <filename>ViShow</filename>
  <name>ViShow</name>
  <!--<android>
    <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[<manifest>
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
        <activity>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="ViShow" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_FORMAT_FILESYSTEMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-feature android:required="true" android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" />
</manifest>]]></manifestAdditions>
  </android>-->
  <iPhone>
    <InfoAdditions><![CDATA[<key>UIRequiresPersistentWiFi</key>
<string>NO</string>
<key>UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend</key>
<true />
<key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
<array>
    <string>1</string>
</array>
<key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
<string>8.1</string>
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>ViShow</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.wenwei.ViShow</string>
    </dict>
</array>]]></InfoAdditions>
    <requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>
  </iPhone>
  <initialWindow>
    <title>ViShow</title>
    <content>ViShow.swf</content>
    <visible>true<isible>
    <!--<aspectRatio>portrait</aspectRatio>
   <renderMode>direct</renderMode>
    <systemChrome>standard</systemChrome>
    <aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>  -->
    <fullScreen>false</fullScreen>
    <systemChrome>standard</systemChrome>
    <autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
    <softKeyboardBehavior>none</softKeyboardBehavior>
  </initialWindow>
  <icon>
    <image48x48>icons/icon_48.png</image48x48>
    <image57x57>icons/icon_57.png</image57x57>
    <image72x72>icons/icon_72.png</image72x72>
    <image76x76>icons/icon_76.png</image76x76>
    <image96x96>icons/icon_96.png</image96x96>
    <image114x114>icons/icon_114.png</image114x114>
    <image120x120>icons/icon_120.png</image120x120>
    <image144x144>icons/icon_144.png</image144x144>
    <image152x152>icons/icon_152.png</image152x152>
    <!--<image512x512>icons/icon_512.png</image512x512>-->
  </icon>
  <!-- 
    AIR options:
    http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/File_formats_1.html#1043413

    AIR mobile options:
    http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-5d0f4f25128cc9cd0cb-7ffe.html

    iOS icons guidelines:
    http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html

    Android manifest documentation:
    http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html
    -->

</application>
```

Comment: Make sure oyu have AIR SDK 23 installed and that you have it set to build with the AIR SDK 23 in your project properties. This might help: https://francescomaisto.wordpress.com/blog/tutorial-how-to-change-air-sdk-in-flashdevelop/

Comment: @Philarmon the AIR App Properties works fine, I don't know where is the issue.

Comment: Do you have the environment variable FLEX_HOME set to the correct SDK location?  I run with multiple SDKs installed, and use FLEX_HOME to switch between them.  I've seen this error when using the worng one.

Comment: @BillTurner How to set the correct SDK location, my friend? Can you explain it in the answer?

Comment: I should preface that I'm using Flash Builder rather than FlashDevelop, but I think the path is still used.  I have the Flex SDKs installed in E:\FlexSDKs (yeah, Windows...), with multiple version (just my naming convention, I've got like 4.15.0-18, 4.15.0-23, and 4.16.0-23 where the Flex SDK and AIR SDK versions are listed.).  If I want to use Flex 4.16.0 with AIR 23, FLEX_HOME=E:\FlexSDKs\4.16.0-23.

Comment: @BillTurner i did this.